# How to add dynamically created items into a dynamically created Panel C# WinForm

Tags: c#, dynamic, panel

I have a list combo box and when selections are made triggers the creation of textboxes and labels which need to be filled out.  However because of formating and if the selection is unchecked I think it would be easier to use dynamically created panels then add those boxes/labels to the docked panel.  This way if the box is unchecked I can delete the entire panel and the other panels will slide up without causeing unnessary blank spaces on the page.

I have code to create the panel and I have code to creat the labels and text boxes.  However I am stumped on how to use create the panel and add the boxes to the panel.

Below is the code I am using to create the various pieces and parts currently.

```
public TextBox AddNewTextBox()
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        panel_Request_Specific_Data.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = A * 27;
        if (ControlAcross == 0)
        {
            txt.Left = 90;
            ControlAcross = 1;
            txt.BringToFront();
        }
        else if (ControlAcross == 1)
        {
            txt.Left = 330;
            ControlAcross = 2;
            txt.BringToFront();
        }
        else if (ControlAcross == 2)
        {
            txt.Left = 570;
            ControlAcross = 3;
            txt.BringToFront();
        }
        else if (ControlAcross == 3)
        {
            txt.Left = 810;
            ControlAcross = 0;
            txt.BringToFront();
            A = A + 1;
        }
        txt.Text = "TextBox" + this.A.ToString() + "." + ControlAcross.ToString();

        return txt;
    }
    public Label AddNewLabel()
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        panel_Request_Specific_Data.Controls.Add(lbl);
        lbl.Top = A * 28;
        if (ControlAcross == 0)
        {
            lbl.Left = 10;
        }
        else if (ControlAcross == 1)
        {
            lbl.Left = 250;

        }
        else if (ControlAcross == 2)
        {
            lbl.Left = 490;

        }
        else if (ControlAcross == 3)
        {
            lbl.Left = 730;

        }
        lbl.Text = "Label" + this.A.ToString() + "." + ControlAcross.ToString();

        return lbl;
    }

    public Panel AddPanel(string PanelType)
    {

        Panel pnl = new Panel();
        panel_Request_Specific_Data.Controls.Add(pnl);
        pnl.Name = "pnl" + PanelType;
        pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        return pnl;

    }
```

Comment: Instead of using all the `ifs`, you should use a `switch` my friend

Comment: @LuisLavieri - `txt.Left = 90 + ControlAcross * 240;`

Comment: Cool. even better...

Comment: You are trying too hard to implement your own Visible property.  There is no point, Visible works fine.

Comment: @Hans The information is coming from the database so I have to implement it this way.  Very specific requirments.  I can't create these boxes on the form cause of the need for them to change without changing the application itself. 

So yes making the controls visible or not visible would make them easier but it doesn't follow what requirements of the project are

Comment: A database has absolutely nothing to do with your code setting the Visible property.

Comment: I am creating the text boxes and panels via information for the database. So I can't create the boxes like that.